# Moment.js: Segmenting a duration into Years, Months, Weeks, Days etc

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Does moment provide this convenience?

If I have two dates, can I get an object from moment from which I can destructure information like:

```
const now = moment();
const futureDay = moment('27-09-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
const timeDiff = futureDay.diff(now);

// ... some code here to get an object with the timeDiff

const {years, months, weeks, days} = theDiffObject;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/). Something like this:

```
const theDiffObject = {
    years: moment.duration(timeDiff).years(),
    months: moment.duration(timeDiff).months(),
    weeks: moment.duration(timeDiff).weeks(),
    days: moment.duration(timeDiff).days()
}
```

Comment: Wow, I just needed  to get a little more creative. Thanks a lot @Darren.